# Deleting all values under a specific registry key

Tags: c, registry

Is there an API that will delete all the values under a specific registry key?

for example, I have the following key

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyCompany\Program\Myconfig

under it I have

(Default)
SomeVal
SomeOtherVal
YetSomeOtherVat
...

There might be 10, 20, 100 values there. It depends what you set on the application.
Is there a way in C to delete them all without having to iterate one by one and delete them?

Thanks, code is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SHDeleteKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773486%28VS.85%29.aspx) function from Shlwapi.lib does what you want.

When you only need this on Vista and later OS versions, you can use [RegDeleteTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379776%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it:

```
if (RegDeleteTree("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", "Software\MyCompany\Program\Myconfig") == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    . . .
}
```

This function deletes a specified registry key and all its subkeys.  However, there is an issue with Windows 7 deleting keys on a Windows XP machine using this.  See MSDN for details.